# Getting started with subtitling videos

Tags: subtitles

I would like to practice some of my languages by subtitling videos into these languages. YouTube is the easiest way to consistently do this with a very large supply of possible videos, but I would want these contributions to be useful and also desired by the channel creator.

Are there any platforms that match creators with translators or any valuable channels that would have multilingual appeal and would benefit from this?